# Why do I get `Configuration error[Missing application.secret]` in Play 2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have written a scala method to do authentication and save a specific token in session like this:

```
def logIn = Action(parse.json) { request =>
request.body.validate.map { entity =>
  Authentication.authenticate(entity.username, entity.password) match {
    case "" => NotFound(RestResponses.toJson(RestResponse(NOT_FOUND, "Invalid username or password.")))
    case token: String => Ok(RestResponses.toJson(RestResponse(OK, "Username %s has been succesfully logged in".format(entity.username)))).withSession(TokenKey -> token)
  }
}
  .recover { Result =>
    BadRequest(RestResponses.toJson(RestResponse(BAD_REQUEST, "Unable to parse content type for user authentication.")))
  }
```

}

To test `logIn` method I have written a test method:

```
"A POST request to login a user" should "return OK " in {
running(FakeApplication()) {
  val node = Json.toJson(AuthenticationUser("cristi", "cristi-password"))(controllers.AuthenticationService.authUserWrites);
  val result = AuthenticationService.logIn(new FakeRequest(Helpers.POST, "/", FakeHeaders(), node))

  status(result) should equal(OK)
  contentType(result) should be(Some("application/json"))
  contentAsString(result) should include("succesfully logged in")
}
```

}

I simply don't understand why I receive this error:

```
[info] - should return OK  *** FAILED ***
[info]   play.api.PlayException: Configuration error[Missing application.secret]

[info]   at play.api.libs.Crypto$$anonfun$sign$2.apply(Crypto.scala:30)
[info]   at play.api.libs.Crypto$$anonfun$sign$2.apply(Crypto.scala:30)
```

I am sure it's something about session... but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `application.secret=changeme` to your `conf/application.conf` file.

Comment: I had to add this when doing the POST: `in new WithApplication(new FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map("application.secret" -> "test")))`

Comment: Are there any alternatives other than FakeApplication ?

Comment: For Play 2.4, do NOT set this to "changeme". As per documentation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ApplicationSecret : "When started in prod mode, if Play finds that the secret is not set, or if it is set to changeme, Play will throw an error."